# Merge multiple workbooks in one (new) master workbook using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help on integrating multiple workbooks into a single master workbook. I am trying to use the following macro code. Problem is that it doesn't enter the do while loop. I have verified the path too. Kindle help

```
Sub GetSheets()
Path = "C:\Users\ssehgal\Documents\Excel-Files-For-Macro"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
  Do While Filename <> ""
     Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
     For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
     Next Sheet
     Workbooks(Filename).Close
     Filename = Dir()
  Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
Path = "C:\Users\ssehgal\Documents\Excel-Files-For-Macro"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
```

with this:

```
Path = "C:\Users\ssehgal\Documents\Excel-Files-For-Macro\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
```

You were missing the `\`

Comment: Thank you.. It is working fine.. However I am not able to save the formatting for header. It is changing for some reason.. Is there any way to preserve the color and formatting of the work sheets too?

Comment: This is probably due to having different templates in your workbooks. Not sure if you can do anything about that. Please mark as answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have market it as an answer. Could you please tell how to use paste special in this to preserve the formatting of source worksheet?